# Nesting XIBs in Interface Builder / embedding by reference

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xib

Say I have created an XIB for an icon view. I then want to embed a number of instances of this icon view in a **different** XIB container view **by reference**, so if I alter properties / layout in the original icon view XIB, the instances in the container view XIB reflect these changes.

Essentially, embedding by reference.

Maybe I'm being dense, but it seems the default behaviour of Interface Builder when dragging a view into a container view is to copy everything over, rather than referencing the original XIB? And dragging an instance of the class associated with the icon view into the container view just results in a blank view.

I'm sure there's a way to do this, but I'm damned if I can figure it out. I normally avoid IB like the plague ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a way of doing this directly in Interface Builder. I needed to do something similar to this in my last app. What I ended up doing was just placing a placeholder View in the location where you want your referenced xib and then in your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, etc, you load that xib and place that loaded view as a child of your placeholder view.

```
NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"ReferencedView" owner: self options: nil];
UIView *referencedView = (UIView *)[views objectAtIndex:0];
[self.viewPlaceholder addSubview:referencedView];
```

Alternatively, you can create an IBOutlet in your view controller to hold the referenced view and connect that outlet in IB. If you do, then you won't need to pull the view out of the NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

Notice that now in iOs 5 they already have containerView. For all I know it doesn't show up in XIB. However, the essence is the same.

Make a view, and call that ContainerView. If you do it the XIB style you need to set some stuff manually like alloc]init the child View controller, adding it to the parent and adding the view to the parent's view.

If you do it in storyboard, you can link from that ContainerView to some other controller and create an embed segue. However, it only works for one view controller and you need to the same for the rest.

Then I do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    PO(self.childViewControllers);
    BGCRListBusinessViewController * theListController= [[BGCRListBusinessViewController alloc]init];
    self.listBusinessViewController = theListController;
    [self addChildViewController:theListController];
...
    for (UIViewController * child in self.childViewControllers) {
        child.view.frame=self.ContainerView.bounds;

    }
    //PO(self.ChangeFilter.BackgroundImage);
    //PO
    //self.ChangeFilter setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@] forState:<#(UIControlState)#>

    [self.ContainerView addSubview:self.listBusinessViewController.view];// initialize'
}
```

Tada....

Now look at that childViewControllers collection. That one is new in IOS5. All it does, is to pass viewWillAppear, viewWillDisappear, ViewDidThisandThat, and ViewIamRotatingWillOrDidorWhatever. It does a little bit more than that but I do not care.

So if you aim for IOS4, you can just call all those directly in the parent viewWillAppear, viewWillDisappear, ViewDidThisandThat, and ViewIamRotatingWillOrDidorWhatever respectively.

In my implementation I have a pointer to whichever viewController has the view inside the ContainerView. Such views will get all those ViewWillorDidWhatever function called.

My parent controller also have several children. Most of which are not seen. No problem. Children that are not seen will not get ViewWillorDidWhatever.

This is done automatically by childViewControllers. If you aim for IOS4, look through all your children view controllers' view and see if any of them is displayed. If displayed call their ViewWillorDidWhatever.

There is also some additional delegate that notify whether a child is added to a parent or whatever. I didn't use that and don't know what it's used for.

Finally some view may want to be dismissed. The parents should do that. I accomplish that with notification. But that's beyond the question already. IOS already have such function for modalViewController.